# Choose button while pressing enter button

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms, button, form-submit

I have a submit button and back button in my asp.net webform. I need to use the submit button when pressing enter, but it's going to the back button instead.

Please help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your section in a Panel - then you can use the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property to set your submit button to be the default when enter is pressed.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MyPanel" DefaultButton="MySubmitButton">
    ... put your form here
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyCancelButton" Text="Cancel" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MySubmitButton" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Can i use "UseSubmitBehaviour" property of button ?

i am using a view now there is no panel

Comment: No - that property just says whether to use the browsers submit behavior or use the standard asp.net postback behavior.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default button for you form or panel

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="MySubmitButton">
```

Or intercept the key presses in JS:

Example uses YUI to help :)

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(document, "keydown", enterKeyPress);

});

function enterKeyPress(ev) {

    ev || (ev = window.event);
    var code = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : (ev.charCode ? ev.charCode : ev.which));

    // pressed ENTER get TAB
    if (code == 13) {
        try {

          var button = document.getElementById("you button client id");
          if (button != null) button.click();

        }
        catch (Error) {
            logError(Error);
        }
        YAHOO.util.Event.preventDefault(ev);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for the defaultbutton.  I had an <asp:imageButton/> which was firing instead of the login button when the user hit Enter.  Setting the default button on the form did the trick.